# Is there a modern printing of the book Doros Rishonim?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

Rabbi Yitzchak Issac HaLevi wrote a 6 volume set of books entitled Doros Rishonim. The only version I found is on Hebrewbooks.org from the 60's. Is there a more recent printing of these books (printed by a publisher) or a new edition?

Comment: Could you clarify, whether you simply needed a new print-out of the old book from HB.org (in this case accept the answer below), or you were looking for a new edition of the book?

Comment: I'm asking about a new edition.

Comment: Then please edit your question

Answer (score 1):

The correct title is "Doros HaRishonim".

As far as I know, it was NEVER reset in new type.

The edition from the 60's, was a photo offset reprint.

It can be reprinted by special order, for a reasonable price.

Just follow the links on the bottom of the HebrewBooks page: "Order Print Version (External site)".

http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/t/7639

Or on Amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/Sefer-Doros-haRishonim-Vol-Hebrew/dp/B00BE3SH5M](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BE3SH5M)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/37801)

Comment: I answered both about a new edition, and about a reprint more recent than the 1960's.

Comment: @Kazibácsi It seems to me that this post is a valuable response to the question. The first line assists in finding more information. The second line answers the question directly: "AFAIK no." The rest of it attempts to provide a next-best solution.

Comment: @Isaac As there's a misleading word (printing) in the question, it's hard to say what the OP was looking for.